# Athena API get current number of Queries running concurrently

Tags: amazon-athena

I have failures in my system due to [Athena Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html). Athena has a limit of running only 5 concurrent queries.

My solution is, I want my system to check the current number of queries running concurrently in Athena and if it is less than 5 then I want to execute my query else wait for some time and check again.

Is there an Athena API which returns `current number of queries running concurrently in Athena`

Note
I can increase the limit with a request which I want to keep as my last option plus it is not scalable solution

Comment: The limit has since been raised to 20 concurrent queries, and you can contact AWS to further increase it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to achieve this is through multiple AWS API calls.

First, you have to call the `aws athena list-query-executions` method to get all recent execution IDs.

Afterwards you can query the status of those IDs through the following call:

`aws athena batch-get-query-execution --query-execution-ids {ids}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also retry on throttling exceptions. Using Exponential backoff with jitter gives a good chance of queries succeeding in subsequent efforts.

See related [AWS blog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html).